# IdentityServer3 - Custom Login and Registration Screen

Tags: identityserver3

We are planning to integrate the identity server 3.

We have our own login page which has following:

1. Login section
2. Account Registration Section,

Is it possible to have a custom login page for identity-server authentication which will have above sections

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, see the documentation on [customizing views](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customizingViews.html)

> The views in IdentityServer can be customized in one of two ways: 1)
>   Customize the HTML templates provided by the DefaultViewService, or if
>   more control is needed 2) define a custom IViewService

Comment: Extra to this, the Identity Server team recommends you consider Account Registration separate from Identity Server. It should be treated as another application. You can always link off to it in your custom view.